# Concatenate Date and Time as DATETIME in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a trouble in combining date and time to `DATETIME`. I have an existing table with data so I can't change it to `Datetime2`.

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(StartDate DATE, StartTime Time)

INSERT INTO @t1 
VALUES('2018-02-28','08:00:00')

SELECT 
    CAST(CONCAT(StartDate, ' ', StartTime) AS DATETIME) 
FROM @t1
```

The error shown is:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't `concat()`.  Just add but they both need to be `datetime`:

```
select cast(startdate as datetime) + cast(starttime as datetime)
```

Comment: Thank you. But If its possible to ask, Why `concat` shows that error?

Comment: @FrostyPinky . . . You would have to print out the string to see what it looks like.  It is probably obvious why it cannot be converted to a `datetime`.

Answer (score 4):

The cast fails because the time component of the `datetime` data type has less precision than the `time` data type, as described on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which is a useful reference for the various date and time types offered by SQL Server. As you can also see on that page, SQL Server has a `datetime2` data type that offers greater precision; if you had used that in your `cast`, I don't think you would have had a problem.

Gordon's solution is a good one in that it avoids the need to deal with conversions to and from strings in the first place. Just be aware that combining a `date` and `time` into a `datetime` may involve a loss of precision. See [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server) on the Stack Exchange DBA site for a solution with `datetime2` that retains the precision of the original values.

Comment: This is called the solution with precise directions. Yes, it will work fine if we use `datetime2` instead of `datetime`. Most of time people feel lazy to go through the description which is really bad but I prefer the solution with good description as this. Thanks (+1)